# The grid is missing on Firefox but works on chrome with narrow width

Tags: css

## [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/knztkhma/)

[This is my page](http://122.116.92.169:5001/#), when you make the browser width less than 960 px

The first gird box will be diappeared on Firefox,

But it still shows on Chrome.

How to make it has the same behavior on both Chrome and Firefox

## Css

```
.container {
  .categorysection {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:960px;
    &.grey {
      background: #eee;
    }
  }
  .grid-col {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 6px;
  }  
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .grid-col {
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ sample as we cannot view your local ip address. and/or paste your html code as well.

Comment: @Bala actualy I think the site link should be work. have you tried it ? and i ll try to creat a jsfiddle , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that page title that says "finance". That title is floating left, and pushing the first block off screen.

You can either remove the floating from it, or clear the floating flow from the columns:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .grid-col {
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the float:left on the header (.container h3.heading) is breaking it. Remove it and it will work but you'll have to add a "row" class on the h3.